# Sphere is not homeomorphic with its proper subset

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Can we use Borsuk-Ulam Theorem to show that $S^{n-1}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is not homeomorphic with proper subset $A \subset S^{n-1}$ ?

Comment: Show that $S^{n-1}\setminus C$, $C \neq \emptyset$, embeds into $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma That looks like a nice proposition. Can you please give some reference?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma is this question slightly easier than that? For $n>2$ this subset would have to be simply connected and compact. And so, $A$ would have to be a closed disk on $S^{n-1}$. For $n =2$, we know $A$ must be path-connected, bounded and so it is homeomorphic to an interval.

Comment: @Juho. rotation plus standard stereographic projection.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma That is something I expected, since the result is clear in a sense of "rubbersheet" geometry.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood You'd still need a "heavy" theorem that simply connected compact subsets are homeomorphic to closed disks on $S^{n-1}$, if that's indeed the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we can:

Suppose $h: S^{n-1} \rightarrow S^{n-1}\setminus A, A \neq \emptyset$, is a homeomorphism between the sphere and its proper subset.

By first rotating $A$ to contain the north pole, followed by the standard stereographic projection shows that there is an embedding  $e:S^{n-1}\setminus A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

Apply Borsuk-Ulam to $e \circ h: S^{n-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, which is continuous as the composition of continuous functions.

We immediately get a contradiction to the fact that $e \circ h$ is 1-1 (as the composition of 1-1 maps).